# Extracting data from a string in Bash

Tags: json, bash

I have data pulled via curl which looks like this:
`foo=[{"date":"2020-06-14","visitors":"323","pageviews":"392"},{"date":"2020-06-15","visitors":"152","pageviews":"172"}`

What I want to do is add all of the visitor numbers and assign them to a variable, and add all of the pageviews and assign them to a variable.

I want to disregard the rest of the data.

I have no idea where to start with this.

Comment: you can start by looking at  `awk`

Comment: @CharybdeBE `jq` would be more suited as it is speciffically designed to handle json

Comment: @Aserre OP was only mentioning string in the title, but in a result from curl which we cna be sure is json, that true

Comment: @Heinz As it is your question lacks details. Usually, we expect askers to show their input, an example of their expected output, and what they already tried. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62711581/edit) your question to add those missing elements.

Comment: @Heinz Instead of `curl` you could have a look at [tag:xidel]. It can retrieve _and_ parse the JSON data you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing your pageview sum with parsing the JSON reply with `jq`:

```sh
json_answer='[{"date":"2020-06-14","visitors":"323","pageviews":"392"},{"date":"2020-06-15","visitors":"152","pageviews":"172"}]'

page_views="$(jq -r '[.[].pageviews|tonumber]|add' <<<"$json_answer")"

echo "$page_views"
```

Output:

> `564`